# Subspace Topology - Derived Sets Comparisons

Tags: general-topology

Let X be the set **R** of real numbers equipped with the standard topology, let Y be the half-line [0,$\infty$) equipped with the subspace topology, and let A be the interval [0,1). Compare the sets A$^{\circ}$ (the interior of A), Cl(A) (the closure of A), Fr(A) (the frontier of A), and A' (the derived set of A) computed relative to X with the same sets computed relative to Y.

With respect to X:
A$^{\circ}$ = (0, 1),
Cl(A) = [0, 1],
Fr(A)= {0, 1},
A'= [0, 1]

With respect to Y:

A$^{\circ}$= (0, 1),
Cl(A)= [0, 1],
Fr(A)= {0, 1},
A'=

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: Fixed--sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: In the future please add to your question something that would show where exactly you have the problem.

**Hint 2**: As you can guess the difference will be "around" point $0$. Indeed, $A=[0,1)$ in $Y$ can be obtained as $Y\cap (-1,1)$, for example, that is $A$ is open in $Y$, but not in $X$.